# Download Azure Devops artifact in Python

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-devops, artifact

I am able to use Azure Rest API in Python (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) to get a download URL for an Artifact e.g.

```
artifacts = build_client.get_artifacts(project_name, build_id)
```

I then want to download them all with something like

```
for artifact in artifacts:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(artifact.resource.download_url, artifactDownloadPath + artifact.name)
```

However rather than downloading the artifact it downloads the HTML page. The same link does work in a web browser.

How can I download the artifacts like I would in YAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import requests in your script and use this API of type GET:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{build_id}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.0&%24format=zip](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds/%7Bbuild_id%7D/artifacts?artifactName=%7BartifactName%7D&api-version=6.0&%24format=zip)

The artifact name is the name you provide in the publish build task in your build pipeline (by default it is drop)

Then retrieve the contents and create the file locally.

```
resp = requests.get(api, auth=("", PAT))
with open(f"{artifact_name}.zip", "wb") as f:
 f.write(resp.content)
```

You'll then get a zip file of the published artifacts in the current working directory.

Comment: I was just missing the `auth=("", PAT)` bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have API version 6.0 for python package download for Azure DevOps Artifacts:

Below is the API, this can be used in any UI

```
GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/pypi/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}/{fileName}/content?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

You can check all the [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/python/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters) from Azure Docs

Comment: Thats the incorrect API, OP was asking for build artifacts. Then again, the question wasnt clear from OP.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use Powershell to do this (which I guess can be called from Python if wanted) by abusing the registry + Microsoft Edge.

```
taskkill > $null /im msedge.exe /f /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING" 
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" -Name "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" -Value "C:\MyDownloadDirectory\"        
start $artifact.resource.downloadUrl
```